# Incorrect image displayed when Gigya opens Google Plus share modal

Tags: google-plus, gigya

I'm working with Gigya's Share Bar javascript api and am having an issue with google plus sharing. I have separate UserAction objects for facebook, twitter and google plus to display different text and linkbacks. I'm adding a media item (image) to the facebook and google plus actions to share that image along with the text. Facebook is sharing the correct image, however, google plus is displaying a different image. I have no idea where this image is coming from. Text and link are correct on both, but the image is frustratingly incorrect.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this? Is there something different that must be done for google plus shares?

Comment: Can you give a specific URL that exhibits this, along with graphic samples of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Test your target URL with Google's structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).
2. [Read the snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) to understand how the Google crawler determines what to use in the share preview.

Comment: Thanks for the links, both were helpful in sorting out what was actually going on. Though, is there no way to _force_ a different image to be used when sharing a page?

Comment: For Google+ if you specify schema.org microdata for an image, it will always use that image. If you need that to be dynamic, it will have to be done via a server-side language because the crawler doesn't execute JavaScript.

Comment: Gotcha, this instance is actually sharing the link to another page, not the page it's currently on, so I don't have access to modifying the target page's microdata. Any way to do something on my page to specify micro data for this share?